# Building Kaa application for esp8266

Tags: esp8266, kaa

I am trying to build a demo application using Kaa C SDK for esp8266. I am following official the [programming guide](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/). I am facing error while making the application (terminal screen shot is added).

I have tried changing the compile options as mentioned here [Compiler options for esp8266](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327054/compile-error-with-esp8266-sdk-in-kaa-0-10-0). Also I have changed the linker file as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471505/kaa-example-too-big-to-fit-esp8266?rq=1). Other notifications are gone and overflow is significantly reduced but it still it overflows by 4964 bytes while showing this error.

> /opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: kaa_demo section '.irom0.text' will not fit in region `irom0_0_seg'
>
> /opt/Espressif/crosstool-NG/builds/xtensa-lx106-elf/lib/gcc/xtensa-lx106-elf/4.8.2/../../../../xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/ld: region `irom0_0_seg' overflowed by 4964 bytes
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   `make[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327054/compile-error-with-esp8266-sdk-in-kaa-0-10-0): *** [kaa_demo] Error 1
>     make[1](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Using-Kaa-endpoint-SDKs/C/SDK-ESP8266/): *** [CMakeFiles/kaa_demo.dir/all] Error 2
>     make: *** [all] Error 2

Please help.

[image: Terminal output while making the application]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I eliminated rest of the overflow by disabling some of the compile options. My compile options are

```
cmake .. \

-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../kaa/toolchains/esp8266.cmake \
-DKAA_PLATFORM=esp8266 \
-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MinSizeRel \
-DKAA_MAX_LOG_LEVEL=3 \
-DWITH_ENCRYPTION=OFF \
-DWITH_EXTENSION_NOTIFICATION=OFF \
-DWITH_EXTENSION_PROFILE=OFF \
-DWITH_EXTENSION_CONFIGURATION=OFF \
-DWITH_EXTENSION_EVENT=ON \
-DWITH_EXTENSION_LOGGING=OFF
```

Hope this helps.